# PHP - dynamiclly set array params to extended class

Tags: php, oop, constructor, extends, solid-principles

In my PHP project, I'm implementing **PHP** through **OOP**.
I have `class A` which defines hardcoded path string and an array of params.
`Class B` *extends* `class A` and in `__construct()` method, I define that path and also define two parameters that I want to pass.

In my `prepare()` method I don't know how to dynamically set those two params so I can get them when calling `$this->classB->getParams()` method.

```
abstract class A 
{
    public function __construct(
        private string $path,
        private array $params
    ) {
    }

    public function getPath(): string
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

    public function getParams(): array
    {
        return $this->params;
    }

   public function setParams(?array $params)
   {
        $this->params = $params;
   }
```

.

```
class B extends A
{
    private ?string $name;

    private ?string $address;

    public function __construct(?string $name = null, ?string $address = null )
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->address = $address;
        parent::__construct(
            'path/to/some/file',
            [
                'name' => $name,
                'address' => $address
            ]
        );
    }

public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(?string $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAddress(): ?string
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    public function setAddress(?string $address)
    {
        $this->address = $address;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

..

```
class C
{
   public function __construct(B $classB) { 
       $this->classB = $classB;
    }

public function prepare()
{
    $arrayParams =  ["John Doe", "Forgotten Lane 007"];

    $this->classB->setParams(arrayParams);

    $path   = $this->classB->getPath();
    $params = $this->classB->getParams();

     $c = new B('', ''); //?

    $this->execute($path, $params);
}
```

Result is:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "John Doe"
  [1]=>
  string(18) "Forgotten Lane 007"
}
```

and I want:

```
array(2) {
  ["name]=>
  string(8) "John Doe"
  ["address"]=>
  string(18) "Forgotten Lane 007"
}
```

As I defined it in `B class`.

The example posted here: https://3v4l.org/msoSh

I am new to PHP so help with this will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is that last snippet part of a 3rd class which you haven't described clearly? Are you getting an error from it? You can't declare a class property inside the constructor arguments... `public function __construct(
    private readonly B $classB,
) {}` probably ought to be something like `public function __construct($classB,
) { $this->classB = $classB;}`

Comment: It's unclear what your actually issue is? How do you pass instantiate the last (incomplete) class and pass in the instance of B?

Comment: @ADyson - _"You can't declare a class property inside the constructor argument"_ - You can actually do it just like they have done it: https://3v4l.org/Vd3Qs. (from PHP 8.1) It's unclear what their issue is and how they actually instantiate their classes though.

Comment: I am not sure if it can resolve my issue. After populating class B with required params I want for method $this->classB->getParams() to return array(2) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(8) "Foo Name"
  ["address"]=>
  string(11) "Foo Address"
} @M.Eriksson

Comment: `getParams()` is in class A and are using a readonly property in class A called `params`. Changing `name` and `address` in class B won't change `params` in class A. You need to remove the `readonly` in class A and have a setter for that that you update when you call the setters in class B if you want that to be reflected in `getParams()`'

Comment: @M.Eriksson interesting, it wouldn't have occured to me that it would work, thanks for that (re your first comment with the demo)

Comment: Can you please help me and provide an example for the second part of your answer? Changed read-only part.. @M.Eriksson

Comment: To change the readonly on the `params` property, simply remove `readonly` from it in the constructor on class A (so it's only `private array $params`). The `readonly` part means that it can only be set once and not updated/changed after that, while you want to be able to change it. Then create a `setParam(...)` in class A that you can call from class B to update those params.

Comment: Yeah, I did all of that: Check https://3v4l.org/msoSh But the result is [0]=>
  string(8) "John Doe"
  [1]=>
  string(18) "Forgotten Lane 007" and I want ["name"]=>
  string(8) "John Doe"
  ["address"]=>
  string(18) "Forgotten Lane 007" as I defined those keys in class B @M.Eriksson

Comment: You're missing the array keys. Change `$arrayParams =  ["John Doe", "Forgotten Lane 007"];` to `$arrayParams =  ["name" => "John Doe", "address" => "Forgotten Lane 007"];`

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to be predefined in class B as you can see. @M.Eriksson

Comment: Well, `params` in class A needs those keys to be able to return them. Instead of having `setParams()`, create a `setName()` and `setAddress()` that only update that key in the `params` property then. One way or another, you need to tell class A what value belongs to what key. However, I don't see the point of having the `name` and `address` properties in class B if you want to get them from class A's `params` property. You could simply make `params` protected instead so you can override that property in class B. I get the feeling that you've abstracted things away a bit too much.